# Spring @ModelAttribute binding

Tags: spring, forms, spring-mvc, binding, modelattribute

I want to make sure if I have understood the nature of `@ModelAttribute` annotation right. Here's an example.

```
@Controller
public class GreetController {

    @ModelAttribute("userInfoFormObject")
    public UserInfoForm modelFormObject() {
        return new UserInfoForm();
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "form", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String showForm() {
        return "form";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "processform", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String processForm() {
        return "greet";
    }

}
```

When user navigates to form, Spring instantiates new `UserInfoForm` and adds it to `model`. View template extracts field names and prints the form. When user submits a form and hits `processForm()`, Spring again instantiates `UserInfoForm`, adds it to `model`, and this time `populates it with the POST parameters`.

So, I never need `@RequestParam`'s or manual binding when working with `form model objects` and `@ModelAttribute` annotation - it always does as much work as there's available, and may basically fulfill different purposes on different requests with different payload, with the principle of binding when there's something to bind, but always instantiating and adding to model.

Have I understood the `@ModelAttribute` right and does this use case make justice to it?

**EDIT:**

Actually it seems like `@ModelAttribute` procedure *doesn't bind* attributes automatically, if it just returns a new Object. However, if I *ask for* an Object in `@ModelAttribute` methods arguments, Spring will bind attributes to that object, like in normal handler method. Then it's just a matter of returning that object. This makes sense, as `@ModelAttribute`annotated method will accept anything that request handler does. But still, it's kinda counterintuitive in my opinion.

So here is the code snippet that actually works

```
@ModelAttribute("userInfoFormObject")
public UserInfoForm modelFormObject(UserInfoForm formObject) {
    return formObject;
}
```

Comment: In a word: Yes :-)

Comment: After a research I actually found this to be false. Read the edited partition of original post

Comment: Ok, I didn't make the connection that you were expecting the model attribute to be bound in the request method. It's more usual to annotate the parameter then follow it with a BindingResult parameter to catch any binding problems